# Using ImageMagick, create padded space and write the Modified or Created date on that padded space

Tags: date, imagemagick

I want to create a black padded space below the image, where I would like to write on it the modified or created file date.

I am using the below imagemagick command that does not work as I would like.

It creates a black padded space but above the image.
The date is written not on the black padded space.

```
  for pic in DSC*.*; do convert -background black -extent 0%x0%+0+120 -pointsize 24 -fill white -undercolor '#00000080' -gravity SouthWest -annotate 0%x0%+10+20 "$(stat -c '%y' "$pic")" "$pic" "${pic//.*}-d.jpg";
```

done;

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

This made it correct. It creates a black padded below the image.
Then it writes the modified date of filename on that padded black space.

```
  for pic in DSC*.*; do convert -background black -gravity NorthWest -extent 0%x0%+0+120  -pointsize 32 -fill white -undercolor '#00000080' -gravity SouthWest  -annotate  +100+50 "$(stat -c '%y' "$pic")" "$pic" "${pic//.*}-d.jpg"; done;
```

My whole command for

1. write Date on filename
2. add watermark in extra space
3. Add Modified Date as info on the Image, on the black padded space.
   is:

> ```
> for pic in DSC*.*;        do exiftool "-FileName<CreateDate" -d  "${pic//.*}_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.jpg" "$pic"; done;
>       for pic in DSC*.*;        do convert -background black -gravity NorthWest -extent 0%x0%+0+120  -pointsize 24 -fill white -undercolor '#00000080' -gravity SouthWest  -annotate  +100+50 "$(stat -c '%y' "$pic")" "$pic" "${pic//.*}-d.jpg"; done;
>       for pic in DSC*-d.*; do composite -dissolve 100% -gravity SouthEast /home/elias/Data/PHOTOS/watermark_0.png "$pic" "${pic//.*}-marked.jpg"; done
> ```